# Remove a single character from a varchar field SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with several `varchar` columns that are almost identical to primary keys I have in another table, with the exception of a period (`.`).  I've looked at the `replace` function in T-SQL but the first argument isn't an expression.  How can I remove all occurrences of a particular character with SQL?  It seems like the correct answer might be to replace with a zero length string.  Is that close?

To whomever felt the question didn't exhibit research effort it was mainly due to a misunderstanding of the documentation itself.

Comment: What documentation are you looking at? The first parameter for [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) is a string expression.

Comment: see `Replace` fn at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

Comment: I took the msdn documentation string_expression to mean it had to be a string literal, mainly because the examples provided didn't use a column.  thanks.

Comment: @Oded maybe they are confused by the fact that MSDN docs say string_expression

Comment: Perhaps you should have read the description of [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190286.aspx)...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can update the table directly using `REPLACE` on the column values:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myColumn = REPLACE(myColumn, '.', '')
```

Answer (score 6):

Do you want to remove all instances of the . from the string? If so, you were right about `REPLACE`:

```
DECLARE @Example TABLE
(
    Value VARCHAR(100)
)
INSERT @Example (Value)
VALUES ('Test.Value'), ('An.otherT.est')

SELECT
    REPLACE(Value, '.', '')
FROM
    @Example

-- Replace only the first '.'
SELECT
    STUFF(Value, CHARINDEX('.', Value, 0), 1, '')
FROM
    @Example
```

Edit, making the example a little more useful since I played around with it anyway, I might as well post the example. :)

Answer (score 6):

```
update your_table
set some_column = replace(some_column, '.', '')
```