# Is there a way to remove specific characters from SQL Server Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database table that contains a column for pricing.

Its very old, so it was written before i understood datatypes. so we are using varchar for a money value.

Ive noticed some columns have $ in them, so what I'm wondering is... is there a way with SQL Server to perform an update of the table and remove any instances of non numeric characters or at the very least remove the $ from the string in the columns in one go ?

I hope this is possible.

Comment: Do you want to remove $ from every column within same table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a single character from a varchar field SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938666/remove-a-single-character-from-a-varchar-field-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 7):

```
Update tbl
SET price = replace(price, '$', '')
```

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) is the replace definition