# Remove Decimal from Alphanumeric Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

From a Table T, I want to remove the decimal from the varchar field *ICD10* (alphanumeric ICD10 codes) while also keeping those codes which do not have a decimal. So basically all codes without a decimal.

**Original field**

```
ICD10
-----
F84
F84.0
H93.25
F90.2
E75.02
```

**Desired Output**

```
ICD10
----
F84
F840
H9325
F902
E7502
```

**Attempt**

```
SELECT icd10 FROM T;
```

for the lack of knowledge of which function to use

Comment: a simple `replace` will do.

Comment: Duplicate of [Remove a single character from a varchar field SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938666/remove-a-single-character-from-a-varchar-field-sql-server-2008)

Comment: My apologies. It didn't show up on the list of similar questions or Google indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) function to replace all decimal points with an empty string ''.

```
SELECT REPLACE(icd10, '.', '') as icd10 FROM T
```